Can't delete Cloud CDN origin
I can't delete  Cloud CDN origin using the console or using CLI. The console never loads the origin -- it just goes around and around. The CLI gives me this error message:

root@linux-web-server:/home/info# gcloud edge-cache origins delete recpres
You are about to delete origin [recpres]
Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y
ERROR: (gcloud.edge-cache.origins.delete) NOT_FOUND: Method not found.

This is a screen shot of the console going around and around. What do I do?
Console going around and around
I contacted Google and it has been more than 2 weeks and nothing.

How did you contact Google?

I pay for support and filed a case.

If you already filed a ticket regarding this concern I think they are the best people to seek a resolution for this concern for I believe they have the resources to check your project. This one happened to me before but not specifically in Cloud CDN but in other resources (also deleting some services) wherein it has the same arrow moving round that never stops. Others have red exclamation point while others are grayed out. Depends on what type of service that got stuck deleting.
These steps sometimes work and sometimes need to wait for a few days before it gets fixed.

Clear Cache / delete web history

Log out then Log in back

Try different browser


If these things did not work next is to file an issue tracker so Google Cloud support can check this concern. But since you already filed a case on this concern I believe they should be frequently reaching you for an update depends also on what type of support.


gcloud edge-cache origins delete [target]

is not for Cloud CDN, it's the command for deleting a Media CDN origin. It is a different service altogether. Media CDN is a restricted offering that you need to be allow listed into. The ERROR you are probably getting is because your project tenant is most likely not authorized for Media CDN so it is generating the error.
If you want to use the CLI tool to delete a Cloud CDN backend, you need to use the compute service as Cloud CDN is tied to the Application Load Balancer which is part of the COMPUTE service.

gcloud compute backend-services delete [target]

If your origin is a storage bucket, you would need to use the backend bucket action to delete it.
